# Java User Interface Framework?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, groovy, javafx

I am about to build a UI in Java and I am trying to determine what I should use. I definitely don't want to use vanilla swing.

The one caveat is that it has to be added inside of an existing swing application. I am looking at JavaFX and Groovy Swing Builder. For the former it looks like there is fairly poor support for embedding into swing.

Anyone have another other suggestions?

Comment: If the question is about declarative UI builders, then it's almost a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761237/suggestions-for-declarative-gui-programming-in-java . It's hard to tell right now, though.

Comment: What's the "vanilla" thing I've been hearing everywhere ??

Comment: @OscarRyz Not sure about vanilla, but chocolate Swing is animated http://i996.photobucket.com/albums/af88/taranaingel/Places/swstpgch.png

Comment: have you thought about building your backend with java but using another language for interface? I find most java interfaces quite heavy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The groovy guys are working on **Griffon**: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Griffon.

I believe it is supposed to model a console type GUI like a web UI.

Another possible answer is **JavaFX**. Here's a link to their hello world app: 
http://javafx.com/docs/gettingstarted/javafx/create-first-javafx-app.jsp

Comment: +1 for Griffon. Not so sure about JavaFX though, it doesn't seem to have gained much traction despite the marketing effort that was ploughed into it

Comment: Griffon sports a JavaFX plugin that works with the current JavaFX 2.0. See https://github.com/deanriverson/griffon-javafx-plugin

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using NetBeans?

http://www.netbeans.org/features/java/swing.html

Comment: Why got this downvoted? Building swing uis with Netbeans is really easy as it uses a graphical editor.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you're looking for, but [SwingX](http://swinglabs.org/) might fit the bill.

> Contains extensions to the Swing GUI toolkit, including new and enhanced components that provide functionality commonly required by rich client applications. Highlights include:
>
> - Sorting, filtering, highlighting for tables, trees, and lists
> - Find/search
> - Auto-completion
> - Login/authentication framework
> - TreeTable component
> - Collapsible panel component
> - Date picker component
> - Tip-of-the-Day component

([SwingLabs](http://swinglabs.org/) seems to be down at the moment, though.)

---

**Edit:** On second reading, I guess you were actually talking about declarative UI builders? In that case, I'll refer you to [another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761237/suggestions-for-declarative-gui-programming-in-java/761258#761258) in which I recommended [javabuilders](http://code.google.com/p/javabuilders/), a [YAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML)-based Swing UI builder.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [JIDE](http://www.jidesoft.com) in the past.
It's docking framework is pretty awesome.

Comment: I'd be concerned about the level of community-support available for JIDE