# Java: Create a GUI with XML?

Tags: java, xml, user-interface, swing, frameworks

im searching for the most popular framework to create a java gui with xml definitions. I prefer Swing!

Your opinions are needed, thanks!

Comment: I have been using Swing for about 5 years and would also prefer using it over anything else.

Comment: See [suggestions for declarative GUI programming in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761237/suggestions-for-declarative-gui-programming-in-java)

Answer (score 7):

I have had good experience with **[ANTForm](http://antforms.sourceforge.net/)**: http://antforms.sourceforge.net/.

It generates Java Swing panels from XML. I have used it to build simple GUI apps that execute ANT targets.

Example of the XML declaration:

```
<antform title="Send Mail" 
    save="properties.txt"
    image="doc/images/testlogo.jpg">
    <label>To send a mail, use the following form. Pick a recipient,
 type a subject and a body...the script will do the rest.</label>
    <selectionProperty label="Recipient: " 
    property="recipient" 
    values="address1@somewhere.com; address2@somewhere.com; address4@somewhere.com" 
    separator=";"/>
    <textProperty label="Subject : " property="subject" />
    <multilineTextProperty label="Message body: "
        property="body"/>
    <booleanProperty label="Send immediately: " property="send"/>
</antform>
```

Example of what it produces:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest checking out FXML there is a neat tool made by oracle which can be used for making GUIs the following are some good links to get started.

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/jfxpub-fxml_get_started.htm

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx//scenebuilder/1/get_started/jsbpub-get_started.htm

You don't need to use the SceneBuilder tool but it makes things very easy when creating a gui using FXML.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there are any *popular* frameworks out there for Java, but you might look at [XUL](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XUL) which is what the Firefox UI and its plugins use.

There are some Java-based engines to render [XUL (using Swing)](http://luxor-xul.sourceforge.net/post/links.html), but I'm not sure what state they are in.

Answer (score 2):

I used Apache Pivot http://pivot.apache.org/ and really liked it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) and [SWT/XML](http://code.google.com/p/swtxml/) or [SWIXML](http://www.swixml.org/) for Swing.

Answer (score 0):

[Jaxe](http://jaxe.sourceforge.net/en) is something which I have used for the same.
But not sure if it is maintained now.