# XML or HTML based UI for Java Desktop Application

Tags: java, html, eclipse-rcp, xulrunner

I am working on Java Desktop Application. I have .NET background and have worked heavily with XAML/WPF technology.

Coming to my question, is there any framework for Java which allows me to create UI for the application using HTML or XML. I wouldnt mind to create UI completely based on HTML which calls my Java classes in background. I believe this will allow me to create more beautiful applications for my users.

I am currently using Eclipse RCP platform to build my app, but I am open to suggestions.

How do you guys feel about XULRunner + JavaXPCom + Java Backend (Business Logic). Do you feel it is good enough to make commercial enterprise level applications?

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213838/java-create-a-gui-with-xml   It has several options listed

Comment: If you're using already the Eclipse-Stack you should try XWT, Another approach is Wazaabi (since EMF has a XML-serializer) which has IMHO a renderer for SWT.

Answer (score -1):

JSF might be a good solution. Both Netbeans and Eclipse has a sophisitcated editor for it.

Comment: isnt JSF strictly for server application ?

Comment: sorry in misunderstood the question. There is no standard technology to use HTML forms on the desktop. BMC software has a work management tool called Remedy, that has a form editor. It is capable to render the forms into a webpage or into a desktop client, but their technology is propietrary (and sucks). You should go with the standard solutions like SWT or SWING